# understanding asyncio with long-running computations in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.10

I'm currently working with Python's asyncio library and encountering some behavior that I don't fully understand. My code involves two async functions: f1, which performs a long-running computation, and f2, which is a simple function with a short sleep. Here's the code:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def f1():
    print("f1 start")
    while True:
        print("f1 1")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        start = time.time()
        [3**100 for _ in range(8000000)]
        print("f1 2 elapsed time: ", time.time() - start)


async def f2():
    print("f2 start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    print("f2 end")


async def main():
    tasks = [
        f1(),
        f2(),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I expected f2 to execute and finish quickly after its 0.01 second sleep, even while f1 is running its computation. However, the output I'm seeing is:

```
f1 start
f1 1
f2 start
f1 2 elapsed time:  4.705456018447876
f1 1
f1 2 elapsed time:  4.23239803314209
f1 1
f1 2 elapsed time:  4.644515037536621
f1 1
f2 end
f1 2 elapsed time:  4.337735891342163
f1 1
```

It seems like f2 doesn't finish until after several iterations of f1's computation. My understanding was that await asyncio.sleep(0) in f1 would allow f2 to run its course, but it doesn't seem to be happening as expected. Could someone explain why f2 is not completing until after several iterations of f1?

Comment: Asyncio benefits IO related tasks, not compute tasks. Python 3.10 is still single threaded, so async can't allow two threads to run concurrently, but can allow one thread to run while another thread waits for IO (which is managed by the OS) to complete.

Comment: For true concurrent ***processing*** look into multiprocess or 3.12's multithreading.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, MatBailie. I understand that asyncio is better for I/O tasks and that Python is single-threaded with the GIL. My goal here isn't about running tasks in parallel, but rather I'm trying to understand why asyncio behaves the way it does in my example.

Comment: Does the behaviour change if sleep(0) is changed to sleep(0.01)? Or, if you change the order they're invoked by gather? My guess is that the orchestrator behaves differently when there are still tasks to begin, as opposed to when all tasks are in flight (in which case the first invoked task takes precedence, so constantly resuming before the second task).